# Render only part of the SCNView

Tags: scenekit

I have a scene in which only some rectangular region in the `SCNView` is changing. How can I instruct SceneKit to only render that dirty rectangle (thus, culling nodes outside that region)?

I tried calling `setNeedsDisplay` on my SCNView with a dirty rectangle but that didn't cause SceneKit to render.

`SCNRenderer.render` takes a viewport parameter. Can I somehow use that without having to abandon `SCNView` and its conveniences?